# Access elements to a Point

Tags: c#

I need to work with a Point of type Double thus created the following implementation for this:

```
public struct PointD {
    public double X;
    public double Y;

public PointD(double x, double y) {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}

public Point ToPoint() {
    return new Point((int)X, (int)Y);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj) {
  return obj is PointD && this == (PointD)obj;
}
public override int GetHashCode() {
  return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode();
}
public static bool operator ==(PointD a, PointD b) {
  return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y;
}
public static bool operator !=(PointD a, PointD b) {
  return !(a == b);
}
}
```

In another file, work with `PointD` as follows:

```
public static double absoluteBearing(PointD source, PointD target)
    {
        return Math.Atan2((target.Y - source.Y), (target.X - source.X));
    }
```

However, I encounter the following error: `'Project.Utils.PointD' does not contain a definition for 'Y' and no extension method 'Y' accepting a first argument of type 'Project.Utils.PointD' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I've done all references, but I can not access the `x` and `y` elements.

Comment: Are you sure it's using the right `PointD` type? As an aside, I would *definitely* make the struct immutable, use properties instead of public fields,  implement `IEquatable<PointD>`, and overload `operator ==(PointD, PointD)` rather than overloading it with `object`. Also, your `absoluteBearing` method should be `AbsoluteBearing` to follow .NET capitalization conventions.

Comment: Is your reference to the PointD a project or file ref?  Sometimes people make file references to OLD versions..  Remove the ref and re-add?

Comment: there was an error in your code, I fixed in my edit: public Point ToPoint() {
     return new Point((int)X, (int)Y);
 } it should be PointD right? do you have a Point class as well in your solution or is it just a typo?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel instead of using System.Windows.Point? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The references are correct.

I program in java and need to adapt the code to C#. In Java I used the `Point2D.Double` for that, and that was the only way I found in C#